# How to update styles of Angular Component dynamicaly

Tags: angular

I have a simple Angular Component.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component-test',
    templateUrl: './component-test.component.html',
    styles: [example],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    providers: []
})
```

I want to update the styles from inside the component class. How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you elaborate how dynamically update?

Comment: @RBC9662 got me there. Wish I'd knew. the idea is to get the CSS Styles from a API. And at the initialization of the component to set the styles (**NOT INLINE**) but CSS using selectors, etc, same as `styles: []`

Comment: Dynamically insert a `<style>` tag maybe? Or a `<style>` link ?

Comment: Do you really need to set the CSS style? Would setting CSS classes also be an option?

Comment: @David I want to apply the style css, only on that component

Comment: @rveerd not an option :(

Comment: And should the style apply to child components? If not, I don't really know how to prevent that

Comment: @David yup, should apply to child components

Comment: And can your API can add a prefix to all CSS rules? Cause it'll be css styles, right? Not sass

Comment: @David yes, it will be css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit hacky, but here is a possible solution. If you don't want your styles to leak to other components in your application (but it's ok for child components), you can prefix your styles with the `_ngHost-*****` attribute that angular adds to components.

So your rules will look like

```
[_nghost-ybl-c433] p { color: red;}
[_nghost-ybl-c433] h1 { color: blue;}
```

**component.ts**

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elementRef: ElementRef) {}


private applyStylesFromAPI()
{
    //Find component prefix first
    let compPrefix = Array.from<Attr>(this.elementRef.nativeElement.attributes)
        .find(att=>att.nodeName.startsWith('_nghost')).nodeName;


    //Create style tag and add styles from API 
    let styleElt = this.renderer.createElement('style');

    styleElt.innerHTML = this.getAPIStyles(compPrefix);
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(styleElt);
}

private getAPIStyles(compPrefix: string)
{
   //Retrieve the CSS styles from API, each rule prefixed with [compPrefix]
```

If you cannot modify the API to add the prefix, you'll have to do this client side...

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-js2xx8)