# Override existing css classes with new classes from api

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, scss-mixins

i am having a peculiar scenario in which i need to override the existing classes i defined in the angular component's scss file. Based on the scenario, i will get different styles from the api. Those styles will will have class name of that component with updated styles. I need to update that component and override the existing styling. I cannot use ngclass or ngstyle for this, as i will be getting an string of all the classes in the component with some updated styles. This will be unique for a component i.e each component should override the existing styles defined in its individual stylesheet. How do i override the entire individual style of an component.??
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Would change encapsulation to `None` be too traumatic? You could then override the styles you wanted in a global way.

Comment: @julianobrasil I do not want to override in a global way, i want to override for each component.

Comment: You need to add the new styles by accessing the element after service call. Not sure it is better solution

Comment: How do i add those classes with the styles to the element ???

Comment: You can add a scss class ".inital-styles" to all the styles in .scss (this is just one line for all file) and when you get your styles from API, remove the initial-styles class from the component and apply your API styles on this component via the Renderer API, make sense?

Comment: @RazRonen , how can i apply the classes from the api to the component, never used renderer API before??

Comment: let me build quick example in stackblitz

Comment: @RazRonen that would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Simplified version of your issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxfva4?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts
.Notice how the styles changes after 3 seconds. btw RendererV2 approach is best practice as it doesn't break your app logic if you want to develop on another platform(lets say android/iphone).

Please tell me if this satisfy you and I'll write an answer.

Comment: Can we continue our chat here : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213063/discussion-between-ram-and-raz-ronen

Comment: yes sure we can

Comment: Would that help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503525/how-to-update-styles-of-angular-component-dynamicaly/61506328#61506328

Comment: @David, your answer matches my scenario perfectly. Can you post it as an answer below, so that i can mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: I'll rather close your question as a duplicate then.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches:

**1) Add .initial-styles class to component, take it off when your API call returns and apply your lazy styles.**

**2) Generate .css bundles in your service, Add .initial-styles class to component, all the right .css asset from your component and remove .initial-styles class**

Explanation:

1) [Here's a working demo for this first approach.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxfva4?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.css)

1. Add .initial-style rule that contains all other rules in your .scss
2. When you API returns execute:
   `this.renderer.removeClass(this.d.nativeElement, "initial-style");` to remove the styles. then apply your new styles via `this.renderer.setStyle(this.d.nativeElement, styleProperty, styleValue);`
3. Notice that if your .css API response is just a string like this:

   container-style {color: 'red'}  .header-style { color: 'yellow' }

   then you'll need to do a a little bit of parsing. @Ram suggested this 
    https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36911 proposal to ease the parsing.

2) Following the first approach add .initial-styles class, take it off when you call your .css asset, and then just add the name of the classes via `this.renderer.addClass(this.d.nativeElement, "myclass");`